# Window.Alert() in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert

I found some javascript code on net. I am using it but here I am unable to get the windows.alert() method. Below is my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Javascriptexmple.aspx.cs"     Inherits="MIS_Javascriptexmple" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function Validate() {
      // Get the password entered in the page
      var Pass = $get("MyPass").value;
      // Encrypte the password
      var MD5 = hex_md5(Pass);
      // Run ValidateLogin PageMethod to validate the password
      PageMethods.ValidateLogin(MD5, Done);
      window.alert(MD5);
  }
  function Done(result) {
      // Alert the boolean result returned from PageMethod
      alert(result);
  }
  </script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="md5.js" />
    </Scripts>
  </asp:ScriptManager>

<div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="MyPass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <input id="BtnLogin" type="button" value="Login" onclick="Validate();" />
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

please let me know where I am missing?

Comment: Check your browser's JS console to see if there are any JS errors happening before that point

Comment: It's difficult to recreate this without the ASP.net components.  I'd agree with the comment above to check for JS errors happening before-hand.  If that doesn't help, suggest you repost with jsfiddle limited to just the the failing code.

Comment: NO. It doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 1):

`$get` is not defined. `hex_md5` is not defined. `PageMethods.ValidateLogin` is not defined.
Include the script which defined these functions, and you should be good to go. Like this:

```
<script src="md5script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function Validate() {
      // Get the password entered in the page
      var Pass = $get("MyPass").value;
      // Encrypte the password
      var MD5 = hex_md5(Pass);
      // Run ValidateLogin PageMethod to validate the password
      PageMethods.ValidateLogin(MD5, Done);
      window.alert(MD5);
  }
  function Done(result) {
      // Alert the boolean result returned from PageMethod
      alert(result);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: I found above solution here. http://daron.yondem.com/en/post/7d31987c-6798-40e4-96a4-966ed6e17e4d

Comment: When looking at your site in the browser, click View Source. Look for the line where the ScriptReference is. Click on the md5.js source. Does that file exist to your browser? Does it define the methods $get, hex_md5, and PageMethods.ValidateLogin?

Comment: I put window.alert(MD5); before PageMethods.ValidateLogin(MD5, Done); and it is wroking now.